# TCP Hole Punching Java Example

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, bind, hole-punching

I am using the following code on a local machine :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Just for testing socket SO_RESUEADDR. If set SO_RESUEADDR to true, we can use
 * a single local port to listen for incoming TCP connections, and to initiate
 * multiple outgoing TCP connections concurrently. By this way we can implement
 * TCP hole punching(establish P2P connection traversal through NAT over TCP).
 */
public class TcpPeer2 {
// TCP port is a different source from UDP port, it means you can listen on
// same port for both TCP and UDP at the same time.
private int localport = 7890;
private ServerSocket peerSock;
private Socket serverSocket;

public TcpPeer2(final String serverHost, final int serverPort, final int localPort)
       throws Exception {
 this.localport = localPort;

 Thread server = new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
     try {
       peerSock = new ServerSocket();
       System.out.println(peerSock.isBound());
       peerSock.setReuseAddress(true);
       System.out.println(peerSock.isBound());
       peerSock.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", localport));
       System.out.println("[Server]The server is listening on " + localport + ".");
       System.out.println(peerSock.isBound());
       System.out.println(peerSock.isClosed());
       System.out.println(peerSock.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
       //peerSock.
       while (true) {
         try {
           serverSocket = peerSock.accept();
           // just means finishing handshaking, and connection
           // established.
           System.out.println("[Server]New connection accepted"
                   + serverSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + serverSocket.getPort());

           BufferedReader br = getReader(serverSocket);
           PrintWriter pw = getWriter(serverSocket);
           String req = br.readLine();
           System.out.println("[Server][REQ]" + req);
           pw.println(req);

 //              pw.close();
 //              br.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         } finally {
 //              try {
 //                if (serverSocket != null)
 //                  serverSocket.close();
 //              } catch (IOException e) {
 //                e.printStackTrace();
 //              }
         }
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }

 });
 // server.setDaemon(true);
 server.start();

 Thread.currentThread();
 // sleep several seconds before launch of client
 Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);

 final int retry = 5;
 Thread client = new Thread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
     Socket socket = new Socket();
     try {
       socket.setReuseAddress(true);
       System.out.println("[Client]socket.isBound():" + socket.isBound());
       socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", localport));
       for (int i = 1; i < retry; i++) {
         try {
           socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverHost, serverPort));
           System.out.println("[Client]connect to " + serverHost + ":"
                   + serverPort + " successfully.");
           break;
         } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("[Client]fail to connect " + serverHost + ":"
                   + serverPort + ", try again.");
           Thread.currentThread().sleep(i * 2 * 1000);
           /**
            * PeerA and PeerB
            * <p>
            * Alternatively, A's TCP implementation might
            * instead notice that A has an active listen socket
            * on that port waiting for incoming connection
            * attempts. Since B's SYN looks like an incoming
            * connection attempt, A's TCP creates a new stream
            * socket with which to associate the new TCP
            * session, and hands this new socket to the
            * application via the application's next accept()
            * call on its listen socket. A's TCP then responds
            * to B with a SYN-ACK as above, and TCP connection
            * setup proceeds as usual for client/server-style
            * connections.
            * <p>
            * Since A's prior outbound connect() attempt to B
            * used a combination of source and destination
            * endpoints that is now in use by another socket,
            * namely the one just returned to the application
            * via accept(), A's asynchronous connect() attempt
            * must fail at some point, typically with an
            * “address in use” error. The application
            * nevertheless has the working peer-to- peer stream
            * socket it needs to communicate with B, so it
            * ignores this failure.
            */
           if (i == retry - 1) {
             System.out
                     .println("[Client]Use the socket returned by ServerSocket.");

             socket = serverSocket;
           }
         }
       }

       PrintWriter pw = getWriter(socket);
       String msg = "hello world!";
       pw.println(msg);

       /**
        * Got response from the server socket.
        */
       BufferedReader br = getReader(socket);
       String resp = br.readLine();
       System.out.println("[Client][RESP-1]" + resp);

       /**
        * The client thread of other process will send request. If
        * fail to establish connection with other peer, the Socket
        * return by the ServerSocket will be used.
        */
       resp = br.readLine();
       System.out.println("[Client][RESP-2]" + resp);
//          pw.close();
//          br.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
//          try {
//            socket.close();
//          } catch (Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//          }
     }
   }

 });
 client.start();
  }

  private PrintWriter getWriter(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    OutputStream socketOut = socket.getOutputStream();
    return new PrintWriter(socketOut, true);
  }

  private BufferedReader getReader(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    InputStream socketIn = socket.getInputStream();
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketIn));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   new TcpPeer2("127.0.0.1", 8000, 7000);
  }
}
```

But it is giving me a JVM-Bind Exception.

I have downloaded this code from the following link :
http://ramonli.blogspot.in/2012/03/tcp-hole-punching-how-to-establish-tcp.html

Theoretically it should be working fine and not throwing any exceptions.
It should therefore be a template for TCP Hole Punching in Java.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can replace `Thread.currentThread().sleep(i * 2 * 1000)` with `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(i * 2)`

Comment: Could you please add the Exception you get? Maybe the port you use is already in use?

Comment: false
false
[Server]The server is listening on 7000.
true
false
localhost/127.0.0.1:7000
[Client]socket.isBound():false
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
 at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
 at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
 at java.net.Socket.bind(Socket.java:631)
 at TcpPeer2$2.run(TcpPeer2.java:92)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: @flob Here are the traces that I receive
Yes Same port is being used
That is why I have setReuseAddress(true)
That has to be done for TCP Hole Punching

Comment: You can't bind your client to the same listening port as the server if it is still listening. With the bind you will have exactly the same pair of local(addr:port)/remote(addr:port) which is localhost:7000/*:*. You can bind your client to a random free local port with `socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 0));` but that seems to defeat your target.

Comment: The referred post might not be a good start as its comments show that others have the same problems with its code.

Comment: @flob Can you help with any other code to achieve this?
Basically I want to achieve TCP Hole Punching, all the examples I got use this same method [all are not working]. So how can I resolve this  ??

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done TCP hole punching yet, just pointing at general flaws in that code. Maybe you continue reading about it, looking at implementations in other languages and post your solution here? :-) This codes *make a server socket, bind it, bind another socket to the same port, try to connect to another instance of the program, try to use any connected socket...* seems quite messy and as it never could have run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind your client to the same local host:port while the server is still listening, even with SO_REUSEADDR.

See the [man socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) for this:

> **SO_REUSEADDR**
>
> Indicates that the rules used in validating addresses supplied
>   in a bind(2) call should allow reuse of local addresses.  For
>   AF_INET sockets this means that a socket may bind, **except when
>   there is an active listening socket bound to the address.**
>   When the listening socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a
>   specific port then it is not possible to bind to this port for
>   any local address.  Argument is an integer boolean flag.

You could bind your client to a random free local port with `socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 0));` but that will defeat your purpose.

Comment: Then what can be the way to achieve TCP Hole Punching ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a good code example at hand and haven't done it myself. But it should answer at least that only explicitly included question *What I am doing wrong ?* in your question. So technically this is a valid answer even if it does not solve the underlying problem :-/ Sorry about that.